# Can a generic @ExceptionHandler and DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver play nice?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'd like to implement an `@ExceptionHandler` that prevents all uncaught exceptions from getting to the client. Something like this...

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice {

    private static final Logger logger = getLogger(ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleAnyUncaughtException(Exception e) {
        logger.error("This uncaught exception is being blocked from reaching the client.", e);
    }
}
```

But this is getting in the way of the exception handling performed out of the box by `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`, e.g. to throw 4xx errors on failed `@RequestBody` validations checked with `@Valid`. It seems like `@ExceptionHandler` is taking precedence and returning 500 before the `DHER` can try to return a 4xx.

Is there a way to block uncaught exceptions from getting to the client, but still let the `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` do its job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. I was writing an `@ExceptionHandler` that explicitly handles all the standard Spring MVC exceptions, checked the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-rest-spring-mvc-exceptions) for the list, and ran across the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` base class.

Extending that base class in the `@ControllerAdvice` adds an `@ExceptionHandler` for the standard exceptions with the crucial difference that you don't have to maintain the list should those exceptions change. The `@ControllerAdvice` now looks like this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = getLogger(ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleAnyUncaughtException(Exception e) {
        logger.error("This uncaught exception is being blocked from reaching the client.", e);
    }
}
```